# dplyr error with mutate() when attempting to change variable value based on if_else condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to change the value of a variable using `dplyr::mutate()`. I want to change the value of the column 'certainty' from "unsure" to "likely" if the ID from a character vector is found in the ID column in the dataset. If it does not match, I would like to keep the original value. Here is a reprex with my current attempt:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data <- data.frame(
  ID = c("a100", "b100", "c100", "d100", "e100", "f100"),
  certainty = c("confirmed", "likely", "unsure", "likely", "unsure", "confirmed")
)

data %<>% as_tibble()

id_list <- c("c100", "e100")

data %<>%
  mutate(certainty = if_else(id_list %in% ID, "likely", certainty))
```

The output should look like this:

```
 ID    certainty
  <fct> <fct>    
1 a100  confirmed
2 b100  likely   
3 c100  likely   
4 d100  likely   
5 e100  likely   
6 f100  confirmed
```

Currently I get this error:

```
Error: `false` must be length 2 (length of `condition`) or one, not 6
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the order of arguments in `%in%`.  It is returning the length of `id_list` which is 2 if we use `id_list %in% ID`.  Instead it should be the other way i.e. `ID %in% id_list` e..g

```
1:3 %in% 1:2
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

and

```
1:2 %in% 1:3
#[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Here, it would be

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
      mutate(certainty = ifelse(ID %in% id_list, "likely", as.character(certainty)))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  ID    certainty
#  <fct> <chr>    
#1 a100  confirmed
#2 b100  likely   
#3 c100  likely   
#4 d100  likely   
#5 e100  likely   
#6 f100  confirmed
```

NOTE: `certainty` is `factor`, so it needs to be converted to `character` or add `likely` as another level (if we want to stick to `factor` class)

---

It can be also be remained as `factor`

```
library(forcats)
data %>%
     mutate(certainty = fct_collapse(certainty,
              likely = as.character(certainty)[ID %in% id_list]))\
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  ID    certainty
#  <fct> <fct>    
#1 a100  confirmed
#2 b100  likely   
#3 c100  likely   
#4 d100  likely   
#5 e100  likely   
#6 f100  confirmed
```

Comment: Such an simple solution. In my real dataset `certainty` has multiple levels already defined. Is there a way to change the value to the existing level `likely` without having to convert to a `character`?

Comment: @Sam Added another optioin