# Another length error using dplyr mutate() and if_else()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have another problem similar to by previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581833/dplyr-error-with-mutate-when-attempting-to-change-variable-value-based-on-if-e). As it is not exactly the same I have posted it as a new question.

I am attempting to add a vector as a new column to a tbl, but my vector is shorter than the number of rows, therefore I am using `if_else()` to specify a condition. Here is a reprex and my attempted solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

data <- data.frame(
  ID = c("a100", "b100", "c100", "d100", "e100", "f100"),
  certainty = c("confirmed", "likely", "unsure", "likely", "unsure", "confirmed")
)

data %<>% as_tibble()

add <- c(1, 2)

data %<>%
  mutate(new_var =
           if_else(certainty == "likely", add, NA_real_))
```

This currently gives me the error `Error: true must be length 6 (length of condition) or one, not 2`, but as far as I can understand my condition is of length 2 since `sum(data$certainty == "likely")` returns `[1] 2`.

The result should look like this:

```
  ID    certainty new_var
  <fct> <fct>       <dbl>
1 a100  confirmed      NA
2 b100  likely          1
3 c100  unsure         NA
4 d100  likely          2
5 e100  unsure         NA
6 f100  confirmed      NA
```

What am I missing? Thanks again and sorry if this is a noob question, but I'm still trying to get to grips with the tidyverse!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option with `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
   mutate(new_var = replace(rep(NA_real_, n()), certainty == "likely", add))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  ID    certainty new_var
#  <fct> <fct>       <dbl>
#1 a100  confirmed      NA
#2 b100  likely          1
#3 c100  unsure         NA
#4 d100  likely          2
#5 e100  unsure         NA
#6 f100  confirmed      NA
```

Here, the `length` of 'add' is known to be same as the number of 'likely' elements in 'certainty' and `replace` can do the replacement based on that info.  In the case of `if_else/ifelse/case_when`, the arguments should have the same length as the condition vector.  Here, 'add' have two elements and it is not 1 or the number of rows.  If it is 1 element, then it can recycle

---

In `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', specify the logical condition (`certainty == "likely"`) in `i`, and assig (`:=`) the 'add' vector to create the column 'new_var'.  By default, the non-matching elements will be filled with `NA`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[certainty == "likely",  new_var := add]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those situations when using base R would be better than `tidyverse` or pipes.

```
data$new_var <- NA
data$new_var[data$certainty == 'likely'] <- add
data

#    ID certainty new_var
#1 a100 confirmed      NA
#2 b100    likely       1
#3 c100    unsure      NA
#4 d100    likely       2
#5 e100    unsure      NA
#6 f100 confirmed      NA
```